# mysql regexp help

Tags: mysql, regex

I got field values like this

```
computer-123-553

computer

compputer-233

computer-123-123

computer-900
```

How to get values that have no hyphen or digit (expect computer)

How to get values that have only one hyphen (expect computer- or computer-13254234)

How to get values that have two hyphens (expect computer- - or computer-23-123)

How to get values that have one hyphen and at least 1 digit (expect computer-3 or computer-312)

how to get values that have one hyphen and 3 digits (expect computer-312)

how to get values that have two hyphen and at least 1 digit (expect computer-3- or computer-331-333)

how to get values that have two hyphen and 6 digits (expect computer-123-555)

Comment: Just plugging a useful resource: http://strfriend.com/ :)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where have you got stuck? Have you read the documentation, and is there something specific about it that you don't understand? Without more information, this question just looks like you want us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex matches strings that do not have any `-` in them:

```
^[^-]*$
```

Explanation:

```
^      : Start anchor
[^-]*  : zero or more non-hyphen character(s)
$      : End anchor
```

---

Similarly the following regex matches strings that have exactly one `-` in them:

```
^[^-]*-[^-]*$
```

Comment: **bold** could you please show the code match two hyphens in a string

Answer (score 0):

Unless you post an example of what you've tried so far, people will think that you are trying to get SO to do your work for you - SO is here to **help**, not to **do it for you**.

Post what you've got, and people will point out where you've gone wrong and generally be awesome. If you post nothing, people generally won't help.

If you've no idea where to start (we've all been there), I've found some tutorials that should help you with the basics:

- Brain Bell: [Using MySQL Regular Expressions](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_MySQL_Regular_Expressions.htm)
- Tech Recipes: [Use regular expressions in MySQL SELECT statements](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/)
- MySQL Docs: [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)